# Why can't I delete global NPM package on Ubuntu?

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu

I have this problem, I follow the same instructions and it keeps giving me the same error, also delete some files but nothing happens that I can do

You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.0).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:

- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app

The latest instructions for creating a new app can be found here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/

Comment: Are you saying that you get the error when you follow the instructions _in the error_? Please revise to be more clear about what you're trying and how it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

update create-react-app with `npm update -g create-react-app`

if it still doesn't work try using one of these commands:-

`npm init react-app my-app`

`create-react-app my-app`

Answer (score 0):

- you might need sudo

  ```
   sudo npm uninstall -g create-react-app
  ```
- if this does not work get the path

  ```
   which create-react-app
  ```
- remove the directory

  ```
  rm -rf /pathToCreateReactApp
  ```